# Better exposed filters - collapse all filters after submit

Tags: views

I'm using BEF (Better Exposed Filters) and I want to this simple thing:

Whenever the button Submit (from the views exposed form) is clicked, all filter must be collapsed (must close).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default BEF behavior reloads the entire page after clicking the "Submit" button (at least on D8 - it's been a while since I've worked with BEF on D7). This means you can just add styles + js to have the form collapsed when the page loads; they can expand the form, choose their options, click "Submit", and the form will be closed again when the page re-loads.

If you have a different behavior on your site - i.e. filters that upload the view live, without having to refresh the page - use JS with an .on(click) function to add a "collapsed" class to your form, and use the same styles + js mentioned above to collapse the form.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. I found out that this is happening because I am using exposed form in a block... I'll try what you said... thanks